# SQLite query group by with index is much slower than without index

Tags: sql, sqlite, tree

this is the table columns:

```
  CREATE TABLE [newtable](
  [id], 
  [HLevel], 
  [LeftBower], 
  [RightBower], 
  [NodeNumber], 
  [NodeCount], 
  [SortPath], 
  [ID:1] INT, 
  [parent] INT, 
  [name] TEXT, 
  [folder] NUM, 
  [size] INT);
```

with indexed **parent**,

```
select pid ,sum(size)
from (select id as pid, leftbower as lft, rightbower as rgt 
      from newtable
      where parent = 1 and folder = 1
     ) as base join
     newtable
     on newtable.id > base.lft and newtable.id < base.rgt 
group by pid
```

this query takes 9000ms~10000ms, while this takes 200ms.( output is the same)

```
drop table temp;

create table temp as
    select pid ,newtable.size
    from (select id as pid, leftbower as lft, rightbower as rgt
          from newtable
          where parent =1 and folder = 1
         ) as base join
         newtable
         on newtable.id> base.lft and newtable.id<base.rgt ;

select pid, sum(size)
from  temp
group by pid;
```

but, without indexed parent,
the previous takes only 1200ms ,while the other one takes 650ms!

This is really strange, can anyone give me a clue?

Comment: What's the [`EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`](https://sqlite.org/eqp.html) output of the two versions?

Comment: You might be interested in the sqlite3 shell's [.expert](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#index_recommendations_sqlite_expert_) command for suggesting indexes for a query, too. From a quick glance I suspect that indexes on `id` and `parent, folder` will be more useful than just one on `parent`, but I haven't looked at the queries too deeply.

Comment: You have two queries and four timings.  I can't tell what your question is.